# Changing one TextBox value zeros another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, global-variables

Me again.  I don't know why I can fly with Windows forms but no text or website is getting me to understand web forms...sigh.  So here's the program snippet now:

```
<script runat="server">

Protected principle As Single = 0.0
Protected months As Single = 0.0
Protected rate As Single = 0.0

Protected Sub PrincipleTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If IsPostBack Then
        Validate()
        If IsValid Then
            principle = Single.Parse(PrincipleTextBox.Text)
            PrincipleTextBox.Text = FormatCurrency(principle)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub TimeTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If IsPostBack Then
        Validate()
        If IsValid Then
            months = Single.Parse(TimeTextBox.Text)
            TimeTextBox.Text = FormatNumber(months, 0, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.False, TriState.True)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And it goes on.  Now, enter a valid number in the PrincipleTextBox and principle appears to set to that value, awesome.  Enter a value in the TimeTextBox and principle reverts to 0.0.  Why?  How does a variable get set and then unset?

Once again, thanks for any suggestions or guidance.  I know there are other things I need to add (TryParse, for one), but I just need to solve this issue before proceeding.

Comment: Since you mentioned Web Forms, I figured [tag:asp.net] and [tag:vb.net] are better targeting your platform than [tag:vba]

Comment: Is this in the code behind or are you running this as a script? on the aspx page? I'm confused why your not doing this in the code behind file if that's the case

Comment: Yes, this is code on the page.  What is a 'code behind file'?

Comment: Can you right click on your .aspx page in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, and click View Code, that will take you to the code file for the aspx page.

Comment: Oh, right, this is that.

Comment: O.k., no one seemed to know that global variables are meaningless in Visual Basic for the web.  Once I removed those and just read the data directly from the TextBoxes as needed, it worked.

Why are we allowed to declare global variables if they are useless?  Seems like a big frickin' bug to me.  Anyway, I got the darn thing to work.